# WPF datagrid template

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I want to make a WPF datagrid look similar to the HTML grid in the following picture:

http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/2563/saltoftheearth.jpg

Does anyone know an easy way to do this ?

Regards,
S.

Comment: Did you even try setting any of the properties of DataGrid, like Background, etc? You know that VS has an object explorer AND intellisense so that you can see all the properties, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it look like this ( http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/9417/failedwpfdatagridstylin.jpg ) using the following code in a resource file. However, it still does not look like the HTML counterpart (  http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/2563/saltoftheearth.jpg )....It has to many borders .... Any ideas on how to make this WPF datagrid look nicer ?

Value="12" />

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridCell}" >
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" 
            Value="Tahoma" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"   
            Value="12" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGrid}" >
    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" 
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" 
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" 
            Value="Cell" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" 
            Value="Single" />
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" 
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" 
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" 
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" 
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" 
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" 
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" 
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly"
            Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here, at [C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Articles/ArticleListing.aspx?SectionID=1&SubSectionID=191), there are lots of useful tutorials there, and Im pretty sure you can find it, like [this one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WpfDGP109272009111405AM/WpfDGP1.aspx).